# SQL Server 2008 Union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I have two tables:
Table A

```
ID   Date       Answer
 1    1/1/16
```

Table B

```
ID   Date        Answer
1     1/1/16       Yes
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM B
```

Output:

```
Id  Date        Answer
1    1/1/16       Yes
1    1/1/16
```

What I would like to see is

```
 Id  Date        Answer
 1    1/1/16       Yes
```

Merging blanks. Essentially I would like to count when a customer (pk) Answers a question on that date once. So I want a unique line per ID and Day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a full outer join with a Coalesce would be a better choice?

```
 SELECT coalesce(t1.id, t2.id), coalesce(t1.date,t2.date), coalesce(t1.answer, t2.answer) 
 FROM tableA t1 FULL OUTER JOIN tableb t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date
```

You could also wrap up your UNION in a subquery and take the `max(Answer)` grouping on `ID` and `Date`. I'm not sure which would be more economical though.

Answer (score 0):

I have used subquery.

```
SELECT  [ID]
       ,[Date]
       ,MAX([Answer]) as Answer
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM TableB) AS X
GROUP BY [ID],[Date]
```